# Calling a subclass constructor with a variable affecting the super constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to create a class Mammals extending the abstract class Animals which can be called from the main method with an int determining what the String species contains. However, the integer does not affect the String in any way in my code below because it's necessary for the call to the super constructor to be the first statement in the constructor of the subclass. How can I call the super constructor again with the "actualized" String? I already tried to create an overloaded constructor in the subclass and call that first, but this didn't seem to work.

```
public abstract class Animals {
  protected String species;
  public Animals(String species) {
    this.species = species;
  }
}
class Mammals extends Animals{
  static String species;
  public Mammals(int speciesNumber) {
    super(species);
    if(colorNumber == 0){
      species = "Dog";
    }
    else if(speciesNumber == 1){
      species = "Cat";
    }
    else if(speciesNumber > 1){
      species = "Horse";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

once you pass a value, you pass it. updating the value later doesn't affect what you gave it to before. Easy fix, though:

```
class Mammals extends Animals {
    public Mammals(int speciesNumber) {
        super(toSpeciesName(speciesNumber));
    }

    private static  String toSpeciesName(int speciesNumber) {
        // your if/elseif block here, or probably just a switch/case block.
    }
}
```

NB: Do not duplicate fields like this; if your parent class has a field named `species`, don't make another field also named `species` in a subclass. You aren't overriding anything, you have 2 completely unrelated fields, one of which is 'shadowed', and very hard to access. Bad plan. Also, making it static here is bizarre. Don't do that either. That would mean making more than one of these would fail.